# How can I know whether the point is a maximum or minimum without much calculation?

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions, derivatives, curves

> Find the maximum and minimum of this function and state whether they
>   are local or global:
>
> $$f: \mathbb{R} \ni x \mapsto \frac{x}{x^{2}+x+1} \in \mathbb{R}$$

\begin{align*} 
f'(x)&= \frac{-x^{2}+x}{\left(x^{2}+x+1\right)^{2}}\\
f'(x)&=0 \iff \frac{-x^{2}+x}{\left(x^{2}+x+1\right)^{2}}=0 \iff -x^2+x=0 \iff x(1-x)=0, \end{align*}
which gives $x_{1}=0, x_{2}=1$. Here comes the disturbing part, we need to know if these are maximum or minimum and for this we usually used the second derivative. But this would be soo exhausting, I don't even  want think of doing it. There must be an easier way and I remember someone here has even recommended me using monotony somehow.

But how can we do this here? Please do tell me, at home I got enough time to use second derivative but surely not in the exam : /

Comment: Just look at the *sign* of the *first* derivative to either side of the critical points. This is called the "first derivative test."

Comment: Maybe you can explain easier? My English isn't that good :P So you are telling me to look at the $x_{1,2}$ signs, right? One is positive, the other one negative. And you are saying that I can see whether it's maximum / minimum from these signs? Or I understood you wrong?

Comment: No, not the signs of $x_1, x_2$. The signs of $f'$ to the left and right of $x_1$, $x_2$. If $f'(c)=0$ and there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $f'(c-a)<0$, $f'(c+a)>0$ for all $a\in(0,\epsilon)$, then $f(c)$ is a local minimum. (Why? Because $f'(x)<0$ on $(c-\epsilon,c)$ implies $f$ is decreasing there. Etc. Draw a picture.) Or you can Google the phrase "first derivative test."

Comment: I would say $\left(\frac{x}{x^{2}+x+1}\right)'=\frac{1-x^2}{(x^{2}+x+1)^2}=0\Rightarrow x_{1,2}=\pm 1$

Comment: Thanks I will edit this now.

Comment: I think @symplectomorphic is saying you can look at $f'(-2)=-\frac{1}{9}<0$ and $f'(0)=1>0$ and $f'(2)=-\frac{5}{49}<0$, which with continuity of the derivative leads you to the conclusion that $f(-1.62\ldots)$ is a local minimum and $f(0.62\ldots)$ is a local maximum.  For the question of the global maximum and minimum you also need to look at the  extremes

Comment: @Henry: thanks for pointing out the global part of the question, which I did not see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume your $f'(x)=0$ at $x=x_0$. Then there are three cases:

- if $f'(x)<0$ around $x=x_0^-$ and $f'(x)>0$ around $x=x_0^+$ then it is a minimum.
- if $f'(x)>0$ around $x=x_0^-$ and $f'(x)<0$ around $x=x_0^+$ then it is a maximum.
- if $f'(x)$ does not change sign around $x=x_0^-$ and $x=x_0^+$ then it is a turning point (provided that the second derivative exists).

In your case:

- the second one is true for $x_0=1$. Hence, it is a maximum.
- the first case is true for $x_0=-1$. Hence, it is a minimum.

You can see it in the following figure as well

[image]

Comment: Do second derivative test..

Comment: @JimmyR.: the second derivative test is not needed. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your expression for the derivative is wrong, but I'll let you sort that out. What is important is that:

1. $f(0)=0$;
2. there are just two values of $x$ for which $f'(x)=0$, and one of them is positive, the other negative;
3. $f(x)$ tends to zero as $x$ tends to $\pm\infty$;
4. $f(x)$ has the same sign as $x$.

These facts are enough to prove the nature of the stationary points. You should draw a graph if it helps. (You certainly don't have to calculate the second derivative.)

Answer (score 0):

Another way that sometimes works is to compare the values of the function at these critical points. Often you can do this without the need to evaluate the function (ok, here the evaluation is immediate) $$f(x_1)=\frac{0}{0^2+0+1}=0$$ and $$f(x_2)=\frac{1}{1^2-1+1}=1$$ So, certainly $f(x_1)>f(x_2)$ and hence in $x_1$ you have a $\max$ and in $x_2$ a $\min$ (be careful for saddle points). Now, check what happens at $\pm \infty$ (take the limit) to conclude whether the $\min$ in $x_2$ and the $\max$ in $x_1$ are local or global. Spoiler:

> they are global.

Comment: This method doesn't rule out saddle points. You can't "be careful" about saddle points simply by looking at the function values at the critical points.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Thanks for calling it a "method" but if it was indeed one, then it would be formally described in textbooks.

Comment: Sorry I had a mistake, I calculated $x_{1,2}$ wrong so maybe correct it in your answer :D

Comment: Well, whatever you call your answer, it's not a complete one: simply looking at the values of the function at the critical point doesn't tell you anything in the absence of extra information (e.g., multiple choice answers that rule out saddle points, or knowledge about the graph that rules out saddle points, or values of the function *around* the critical points that rules out saddle points...). From $f'(a)=f'(b)=0$ and $f(a)>f(b)$ we are not allowed to deduce anything about the nature of the behavior of $f$ at $a$ and $b$.